# Datasource methods not being called properly when implemented in custom UICollectionView class

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

**Scenario** - I have to create a custom UICollectionView class programmatically which has to be presented in any place I want.

**Code till now -**

***For custom UICollectionView***

```
 class ABSegmentView: UICollectionView,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
        var segmentProperties=segmentControlProperties()//segmentControlProperties is a modal class having relevant details regarding about population of collection view.
        override init(frame: CGRect, collectionViewLayout layout: UICollectionViewLayout) {
            super.init(frame: frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
            self.dataSource = self
            self.delegate = self
            self.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
            
        }
        
        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
        
        func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int{
            return 1
        }
        
        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            print(segmentProperties.titleArray)
            return segmentProperties.titleArray.count//data properly being received over here
        }
        
//not getting called
        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            
            let cell = self.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            return cell
        }
        

        func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize{
            return CGSizeMake(self.segmentProperties.segmentHeight, self.segmentProperties.segmentWidth)
        }
        
        
        
    
    }
```

***Code for adding this collection view in some place -***

```
let segment = ABSegmentView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200), collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout())
        segment.segmentProperties.segmentWidth = 60
        segment.segmentProperties.segmentHeight = 50
        segment.segmentProperties.titleArray = ["heyy","heyy","heyy","heyy","heyy","heyy"]
        self.view.addSubview(segment)
```

So what is getting added is only an empty collection view.

**Reason Figured out -**

On debugging I found that my data source method `cellForItemAtIndexPath()` & `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` are not getting called.

**Question** - I am not sure what I am doing for my required scenario is the right implementation or not. Please amend me if I am missing something somewhere or what might be my mistakes.

***Edit :***
**Answer -**
Thanks to Santosh's answer. I figured out that I misunderstood the concept of `collectionViewLayout`.

***Findings -***

- I have to set a proper flow layout for the collection view as a
  proper flow layout with correct spacing and other values are quite
  essential for a collection view to be properly laid.

  ***CollectionView Flow layout is what lays the UI of collection view i.e the grid view.***

  There are many questions in StackOverflow which relates of data source methods not being called due to improper laying of collectionViewFlowLayout.

**References** that worked out for me apart from accepted answer -

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14681999/5395919

***Other instances when some one can encounter such problems -***

-When we set our cell size quite bigger than our collection view.

-When our cell layout size is too big or isn't appropriately held by the collection view.

Comment: I would call `segment.reloadData()` after adding segment as a subiew.

Comment: @SeNeO no it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `UICollectionViewLayout` to instantiate your custom `collectionView` with `layout`. Try using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. Below code may help you, let me know if it works:

```
let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 20//you can change this value
layout.scrollDirection = .Vertical//or may be .Horizontal

let segment = ABSegmentView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200), collectionViewLayout: layout)
segment.segmentProperties.segmentWidth = 60
segment.segmentProperties.segmentHeight = 50
segment.segmentProperties.titleArray = ["heyy","heyy","heyy","heyy","heyy","heyy"]
self.view.addSubview(segment)
segment.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get datasource updated you need to call reloadData()

Comment: No it  doesn't help out. Tried to reload the collection view after adding it to the subview.